# Different behaviour on returning from startActivityForResult() among Android 10 and 11

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-10.0, startactivityforresult

I have a strange behaviour when I run my app in Android 11 and 10. I have an activity containing a searchview, a spinner and a recycler view to filter and show a list of persons, and a fragment that displays the details of the selected one.

In the onCreate() method of the activity I set the listener of the search view to filter patient list everytime the latter is modified

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                easyLog.error("onQueryTextChange");

                if(mCurrentPosition != -1)
                    mPatientListAdapter.setSelection(mCurrentPosition, false);

                easyLog.error("spinner position --> " + mDomainSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                if(mDomainSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != -1) {

                    if (mDomainSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0) {

                        easyLog.error("spinner position != 0");
                        mPatientListAdapter.getFilter().filter(mDomainSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "|" + query.trim());
                    } else {
                        easyLog.error("spinner position == 0");
                        mPatientListAdapter.getFilter().filter("|" + query.trim());
                    }
                }

                mCurrentPosition = -1;

                DetailsFragment removeDetailsFragment = (DetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
                if(removeDetailsFragment != null)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(removeDetailsFragment).commit();

                MenuItem start = mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_start);
                MenuItem sync = mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_sync);

                start.setVisible(false);
                sync.setVisible(false);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

In the fragment the pressure of a button let the user to start the camera and save a photo

```
// Open camera to let user to take a photo of patient data handling consent
        mPatientDataHandlingUploadButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            // Create image file name
            String imageFileName = "dataHandling_patientId_" + getPatientCode() + ".jpeg";
            File storageDir = mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
            Intent takePictureIntent  = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getPackageName() + ".provider", image);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            if(getActivity() != null)
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, GlobalConfiguration.getRequestCodeImage());
        });
```

The result of the startActivityForResult is handled in the activity

```
// Managing the return from camera after taking the patient data handling consent
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @SuppressWarnings({"ConstantConditions", "ResultOfMethodCallIgnored"})
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        easyLog.error("onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == GlobalConfiguration.getRequestCodeImage() && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            FileInputStream fis;
            File file = new File(mActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                                               "/" + "dataHandling_patientId_" + getPatientCode() + ".jpeg");
            int size = (int) file.length();
            byte[] array = new byte[size];

            try {

                // Converting photo to byte array
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(array, 0, array.length);
                bis.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            file.delete();

            // Saving patient attachment to DB with photo data as byte array
            PatientAttachment patientAttachment = new PatientAttachment(getPatientCode(),
                    InternalCode.CODE_ID,
                    GlobalConfiguration.PatientAttachmentType.data_handling,
                    array,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    false);

            Button patientDataHandlingUploadButton = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.patient_data_handling_upload_button);
            Button patientDataHandlingAlertButton = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.patient_data_handling_alert_button);
            TextView patientDataHandlingStatusTextView = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.patient_data_handling_status);

            mCompositeDisposable.add(
                    Completable.fromAction(() -> mInternalDatabaseInstance.getInternalDatabase().patientAttachmentDao().insert(patientAttachment))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(() -> {
                                    easyLog.info("[onActivityResult] Data handling consent stored correctly. Sending to to remote server...");
                                    patientDataHandlingUploadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setText(R.string.sending);
                                    PatientAttachmentUploadRequest patientAttachmentUploadRequest =
                                            PatientAttachmentMapper.mapToPatientAttachmentUploadRequest(patientAttachment);
                                    mCompositeDisposable.add(
                                            mNetworkInstance.sendDataHandlingConsent(
                                                    GlobalConfiguration.HealthCenter.EASYCARE,
                                                    mApplication.getUser().getUsername(),
                                                    mApplication.getUser().getPassword(),
                                                    patientAttachmentUploadRequest)
                                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                        .subscribe( () -> {
                                                                    easyLog.info("[onActivityResult] Data handling consent for patient with code " + patientAttachmentUploadRequest.getPatient().getCode() + " uploaded successfully!");
                                                                    patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setText(R.string.button_ok);
                                                                    patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setTextColor(mActivity.getColor(R.color.green));
                                                                    patientAttachment.setData(null);
                                                                    patientAttachment.setTimestamp(null);
                                                                    patientAttachment.setDataSent(true);
                                                                    mCompositeDisposable.add(
                                                                            Completable.fromAction(() -> mInternalDatabaseInstance.getInternalDatabase().patientAttachmentDao().upsert(patientAttachment))
                                                                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                                                    .subscribe( () -> easyLog.info("[onActivityResult] Patient attachment for patient with code " + patientAttachment.getPatientCode() + " updated correctly"),
                                                                                         throwable -> easyLog.error("[onActivityResult] Error during update of patient attachment for patient with code " + patientAttachment.getPatientCode())
                                                                                    )
                                                                    );
                                                                },
                                                                throwable -> {
                                                                    easyLog.error("[onActivityResult] Error uploading data handling consent for patient with code " + patientAttachmentUploadRequest.getPatient().getCode());
                                                                    patientDataHandlingStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                    patientDataHandlingAlertButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                                }
                                                        )
                                    );
                            },
                            throwable -> easyLog.error("[onActivityResult] Error during data handling consent storing")
                    )
            );
        }
    }
```

Here comes the problem: in Android 11 I press the button, the camera opens, I take the photo and the app return to the activity saving the photo without problem.
The exact same situation in Android 10 causes the app crash while returning from the camera activity

```
2021-12-27 16:09:20.340 23425-23425/it.*********.easycareprofessional.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.*********.easycareprofessional.debug, PID: 23425
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientListAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
        at it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientSelectionActivity$2.onQueryTextChange(PatientSelectionActivity.java:297)
        at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1521)
        at android.widget.SearchView.access$2100(SearchView.java:113)
        at android.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:2154)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:11621)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6833)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6630)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:140)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6582)
        at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:6449)
        at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:21577)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:21555)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
        at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1593)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1548)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3662)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2021-12-27 16:09:20.341 23425-23425/it.*********.easycareprofessional.debug E/it.*********.easycareprofessional.application.App: [handleUncaughtException] Thread = main (2)
2021-12-27 16:09:20.343 23425-23425/it.*********.easycareprofessional.debug E/it.*********.easycareprofessional.application.App: [handleUncaughtException] Throwable message --> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientListAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
2021-12-27 16:09:20.347 23425-23425/it.*********.easycareprofessional.debug E/it.*********.easycareprofessional.application.App: [handleUncaughtException] Stacktrace --> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientListAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
        at it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientSelectionActivity$2.onQueryTextChange(PatientSelectionActivity.java:297)
        at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1521)
        at android.widget.SearchView.access$2100(SearchView.java:113)
        at android.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:2154)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:11621)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6833)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6630)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:140)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6582)
        at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:6449)
        at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:21577)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4699)
        at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:21555)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
        at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1593)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1548)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3662)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Seems that on Android 10 while returning from the camera the focus goes the searchview like I was typing something in the searchview, and meanwhile all the views that I defined before are now null.

Am I missing something?! Why so different behaviours between those two version of Android!?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: `it.*********.easycareprofessional.activities.examination.search.PatientListAdapter.getFilter()` Your adapter is null as your activity was killed while the camera was on top of it. You should recreate all first.

Comment: Ok this is clear, but why everything is ok while running on Android 11!?

Comment: Normal behaviour is as you see on Android 10. The Android OS determines if your Activity gets killed or stays alive. Amount of memory. Amount of active applications. And a lot of things more that i do not know of.

Comment: So your suggestion is to copy all I do in my onCreate() method into onResume(), so it would work also on Android 10, or there are other guidelines for situation like this!? Thanks!

Comment: Override onSaveInstanceState to save some variable values. Then in OnCreate when its parameter not is null read those values from that parameter. (Sorry forgot the name of that parameter)

Comment: Which variables? It's not clear

Comment: Well you have a nullpointerexception while variable PatientListAdapter is null. You cannot save such an adapter . So recreate.