# How to get image uri from camera intent?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get the uri of the picture that have been taken from device camera. I just tried some of the advices from online but i could not manage to solve this problem here is the my code parts.

```
ImageView petImage;
Uri imageData;

    petImage = view.findViewById(R.id.imgPetPic);
    petImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            try {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // display error state to the user
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageData = data.getData();
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            petImage.setImageBitmap(bp);


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

After that code parts worked. ımageData variable is still null. How do i fix this.

Comment: "ımageData variable is still null" -- since `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`, that is expected behavior.

Comment: Do you have any recommends ?

Comment: Look here how to change your intent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497392/different-behaviour-on-returning-from-startactivityforresult-among-android-10?noredirect=1#comment124618842_70497392

Comment: `am trying to get the uri of the picture that have been taken from device camera. ` So. No. You determine the uri and supply it to the camera app.

Comment: Check this, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback